# Cartodb show route on click

Tags: javascript, cartodb

I have created a map with cartodb which shows the train connection between cities. For this I have created two databases: The first one (cities) contains the information about the cities, route, order. Eg city: hamburg route: 1 order:1, city:lübeck route:1 order:2. In the second database (verbindungen) I have made a line between cities with the same route number. In my map I have added each database as a layer.
When I load the map only the cities are shown. Now I want to be able to click on one city and only the connection from/to this city are supposed to be shown.

This is my code so far:

```
var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'docu', format: 'geojson' });

    function showFeature(route) {
      sql.execute("select*from verbindungen where route = {{route}}", {route: route} ).done(function(geojson) {
        if (route) {
          map.removeLayer(route);
        }
        route = L.geoJson(geojson, { 
          style: {
            color: "#000",
            opacity: 0.65
          }
        }).addTo(map);
      });
    }

cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
.addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer) {

layer.setInteraction(true);

var sublayerVerbindungen = layer.getSubLayer(1);
sublayerVerbindungen.hide()
var sublayerCities = layer.getSubLayer(0);
sublayerCities.show();

sublayerTerminals.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
    showFeature(data.route)
});
})
.on('error', function() {
  //log the error
});
```

I have tried to use this example: http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/d20063afd2c96a733002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl,
{https: true,
            legends: false,
            cartodb_logo:false,
            layerIndex: 1
})
.addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer) {



var sublayerVerbindungen = layer.getSubLayer(1);
sublayerVerbindungen.hide();
sublayerVerbindungen.setInteractivity('cartodb_id, a_route, the_geom, informationen_zur_route');
sublayerVerbindungen.setInteraction(true);

var sublayerCities = layer.getSubLayer(0);
sublayerCities.show();
sublayerCities.setInteractivity('cartodb_id, a_route, the_geom');
sublayerCities.setInteraction(true);

sublayerCities.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
    console.log(data.a_route);
    var newSql = "SELECT * FROM verbindungen WHERE a_route=" + data.a_route;
    console.log(newSql);
    sublayerVerbindungen.setSQL(newSql);
    sublayerVerbindungen.show();
});
})
.on('error', function() {
  //log the error
});
```